# basic installation required for CUDA hello world program?

Tags: cuda

I am very new to CUDA. Already know some C and Linux. I want to start for CUDA programming and want have a look over its scope.

1) From where i can start?

2) What all installation i need?

3) I am not able to install nvcc for Centos5, How can i install it? Is it available for 32 bit? Is anything else required?

I am using OS: Centos5

I already have nvidia 1GB graphics card.

Any kind of suggestions/comments/help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. CUDA Zone has everything you need to start

   https://developer.nvidia.com/category/zone/cuda-zone
2. All you need to install is listed here

   https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
3. For CentOS 5 x86_64, you can install the version for Linux RHEL 5.5. Linux version doesn't support 32bit version except for Ubuntu as shown in the above link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Eric I dont want to re-install Centos5 from 32 to 64 bit.. As it is not available for 32 bit... Then it will be an extra overhead for me to get back my old packages and software ... Is there any way, that i can try this on 32 bit Centos5??

Comment: @Vishwadeep Officially NO.

Comment: Inofficially though, the Ubuntu 32bit package *might* work, but expect to spend some time fixing library dependencies...

Comment: You could install CUDA 5.0 on Centos 5 32-bit.  It's available [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-50-archive) (or just follow the archive link at the bottom of the page that Eric indicated.)  Eric's link is the preferred one to use, since it is the current CUDA 5.5.  The [getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html) for 5.5 will walk you through the steps.  Follow the instructions for "runfile installation" not "package manager installation"